# Connecting to an oracle ebs system

Tags: oracle, database, mysql-workbench, sql

I am interning at a company that uses oracle's ebs that I'm supposed to connect to.
Everyone else here uses windows and use toad to connect to the company's database; everyone but me that is...
I use MySql Workbench and I was wondering if I could connect to the system and how.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly MySQL Workbench doesn't support connection to Oracle database, only MySQL connections are allowed.